# Populate ArrayList with variables inside for

Tags: java

I need to populate an arraylist with variables inside of for. I've managed to get this far. The thing is as the for goes on i need to add each one of them to an arraylist from Scanner.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = s.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Atleticar> atleticari = new ArrayList<Atleticar>();

        String ime;
        String pol;
        int vozrast;
        double vreme;
        String zemja;

        s.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < atleticari.size(); i++) {
            ime = s.nextLine();
            pol = s.nextLine();
            vozrast = s.nextInt();
            vreme = s.nextDouble();
            zemja = s.nextLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're not populating the arraylist, you're reading it. What is `s` by the way?

Comment: @Dominique s is the name of the scanner i just didn't copy the line where i initialize it. I know i'm not populating the arraylist. That is because i don't know how and that's why I'm here.

Comment: What is `Atleticar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the scanner input, instead of iterating over the ArrayList. The body of this loop `for(int i = 0; i < atleticari.size(); i++)` will not be executed since the `ArrayList` has been just initialized and it's size is zero.

```
while(s.hasNextLine()){
  atleticari.add(new Atleticar(s.next(),s.next(),s.nextInt(),s.nextDouble(),s.next());
  s.nextLine(); // consume new line character
}
```

I am assuming that `﻿﻿Atleticar` has a constructor which accepts 5 parameters:

```
Atleticar(String ime, String pol, Integer vozrast, Double vreme, String zemja)
```

Given this we are going to iterate over scanner input line by line, converting individual line into `﻿﻿Atleticar` object and adding them to `atleticari` using [List#add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) method.  Typical line input will look similar to this:

```
lorem ipusm 10 22.4 dolor
sit amet 5 9.99 consectetur
```

that will give you 2 `Atleticar` objects.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I kinda understand it, but where should i put the while code and how can i add the variables with .add() instead of s.next() etc. Should i remove the for loop and replace it with while?

Comment: @binary0011, yes reaplace your for loop with a while loop. As for variables just assign them first and use later in constructor.